# Implement "Did you mean?" with Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, string-search

I'm working on an iOS app. I have a Core Data database with a lot of company names.

When the user insert a company name that does not exist, I would like to show "similar" company names. For example, if the user entered "Aple", I would like to show "Did you mean Apple?".

I know that the technique of finding strings that match a pattern approximately (rather than *exactly*) is called **approximate string matching** or, colloquially, **fuzzy string searching**.

In theory, there are many algorithms, more or less valid: the *Levenshtein distance computing algorithm* and so on.

But in practice, is there someone who has already implemented something similar that can be used *easily* with core data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Use this NSString's category available on GitHub: [NSString-DamerauLevenshtein](https://github.com/JanX2/NSString-DamerauLevenshtein).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Soundex, I believe that is part of the core featureset for SQLite, if that is your underlying data store.

Comment: Soundex will only work for the english language, from most european languages try double metaphone. But I don't think SQLite will support this, so ou might have to calculate the value before hand and search on that.

Comment: Soundex is only available if the SQLITE_SOUNDEX compile-time option is used when SQLite is built. If I am not wrong, the iOS Sqlite does not have Soundex (and in any case would not be easy to use with Core Data)...